# I don't know how to fix my script to Copy a sheet to multiple sheets for our District

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with a script?
Is what I am trying to do even possible? Nothing I try is working, not that I know what I am even doing. I have a script for copying a sheet to other workbooks, and it works, but it only copies to the ones inside the parent folder instead of throughout all of the folders inside the parent folder (not my whole drive). This is above my level of skill, but it has to be possible?????? - I have a District folder that has our RIMP master template inside along with folders for each of our buildings. I need to copy a sheet from the master template to each individual student RIMP workbooks that are inside folders inside the District folder.

Here is my script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pasteSheet = [ {name: "2020 RIMP", functionName: "copySheet"}];
  ss.addMenu("Send RIMPS", pasteSheet);
}
function copySheet() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId());
  var sourceFolder = sourceFile.getParents().next();
  var folderFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  var thisFile; 

  while (folderFiles.hasNext()) {
    thisFile = folderFiles.next();
    if (thisFile.getName() !== sourceFile.getName()){
      var currentSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisFile.getId());
      sheet.copyTo(currentSS);
      currentSS.getSheets()[currentSS.getSheets().length-1].setName('Grade 2020 RIMP').activate();
  currentSS.moveActiveSheet(4);
    }    
  };    
}
```

It works if all files are inside one folder, but they are not. They are in subfolders. The Master Workbook that houses the script in the District Folder, then there are school sub-folders, then teacher sub-folders, and the student workbooks that need the new tab are in the teacher sub-folders. Is this even possible? I can't find anything online that makes any sense to me at all!

Comment: You can get all the folders inside a folder and for each folder retrieved, find the wanted spreadsheet. Why isn't this a viable option? @MichelIeBeitzel

Comment: @ale13 Do you mean pull the list of all the sub-folders in the parent folder, and then loop through all of those sub-folders to copy the necessary sheet to each (student) sub-folder?